# How to run bamboo plan for different repository one after another?

Tags: bamboo

I have my automation suite plan in a repository. I want to run the automation suite once my apk file is published. The publishing APK file is in another repository. How can I run my suite immediately after completing the first job?

For ex; I have a repo 1 with my automation suite say repoAuto
I have another repo with client build for generating apk, sat repoBuild
Both are having different repository.

How can I run repoAuto immediately after repoBuild?

Thanks in advance.
-Mashkur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add 2 repositories in Plan Configuration -> Repositories -> Add Repository.
2. By default, you already have one stage. So add another stage for publishing apk. So repo 1 will have automation suite connected to stage 1 and repo 2 have apk connected to stage 2.

Now if you build the plan, the stages will run one by one. Don't check the manual stage check box.

"Each stage within a plan represents a step within your build process. A stage may contain one or more jobs which Bamboo can execute in parallel. For example, you might have a stage for compilation jobs, followed by one or more stages for various testing jobs, followed by a stage for deployment jobs."-from bamboo